# jQuery select 1 checkbox per row where checkbox is an image

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a project where a user will select multiple checkboxes, but then, there will be a condition that only 1 SELECTION OF CHECKBOX PER ROW.

my html is styled using bootstrap 3.2

```js
jQuery('.imgradio').click(function () {
            jQuery('.imgradio.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
            jQuery("[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
            var rdio = jQuery(this).parent().find("input[type='checkbox']");
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                rdio.prop('checked', true);
            }
            rdio.trigger('change');
        });
```

```css
.row {
  border:2px solid #333;  
}

.imgradio {
background: url('http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/virtual-notebook/16/button_shape_oval-20.png') no-repeat center center;
min-width: 32px;
cursor: pointer;
height: 22px;
}
.imgradio.selected {
background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/playstation-controller-buttons-3/64/playstation-flat-icon-circle-20.png') no-repeat center center;
cursor:pointer;
min-width: 32px;
height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-grey">
    <div class="col-sm-12 noPadding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>Condition 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                &nbsp; 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>Condition 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                &nbsp; 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>Condition 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="imgradio">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                &nbsp; 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

what i have on that demo can only select 1 checkbox in the entire container of the rows, what i need to attain is to select 1 checkbox per row.

the container can contain unlimited rows of checkboxes, so the script should be complex, unfortunately i am a newbie in jQuery scripting. :(

Your help and advise will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse to closest row element and then find element that need be unchecked and for removing selected class. Use:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.row').find('.imgradio.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
        jQuery(this).closest('.row').find("[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var rdio = jQuery(this).parent().find("input[type='checkbox']");
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            rdio.prop('checked', true);
        }
        rdio.trigger('change');
    });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5cfq8w8e/)**

Comment: the checkboxes there will have display:none, so the user can only see and select the round images

Comment: nooblike: its already working fine for radio button clicks. what is the issue

Comment: it doesn't work, the script should let the user select 1 checkboxes per row. the demo you showed doesnt do it. it only selects 1 checkboxes in the entire container. it should select 1 checkboxes per row. so since the container has 3 rows, then the user can select 3 checkboxes. :(

CORRECTION: your code is correct, but how can i make the images do it instead of the checkboxes?? the checkboxes will have display none to it. so the checkboxes will be hidden and the user will only see the round images to be selected :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

Instead of this (dont remove selected to all radio buton)

```
jQuery('.imgradio.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

add this (remove - only inside that particular .row)

```
$(this).closest(".row").find('.imgradio.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/qvz11neu/2/)